# Eclipse indigo, plugin installation not working

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ide, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have downloaded  the latest update site archive for Eclipse 3.7 from http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html here and tried to install it. But installation stuck at 24% every time. No change in 24% after an hour also.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are installing from a zip because you are behind a firewall and can't install from an external update site.

What's like happening is that the install of the google plugin also attempts to bring in other plugins from remote sites, but this fails to download because of the firewall.

If this is the problem, you can fix this by unchecking "Contact all update sites..." in the update manager.

Answer (score 0):

Use GWT 2.3 from,

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.3.0.zip

This is a much stable version for Indigo.

If you use Helios, GWT 2.4 won't create much problems but with Indigo, it has a lot of bugs.

I had been working on Helios and Indigo with GWT for the last 2 years...